# Can you install from one partition to another on the same SSD

Tags: system-installation

I do not have a spare USB, so I am wondering is it possible to install the from one partition to another partition on the same hard drive??

Comment: What do you want to install? What is your current system?

Comment: I want to install linux mint (or ubuntu) onto an ssd for a seperate build. I have a macbook pro which is my only working computer, so im trying to install everything through that.

Answer (score 1):

**Installing Ubuntu from a Menuentry Boot**

Installation onto your hard drive is possible from a booted ISO file. A CD/DVD is not required. An Internet connection is recommended but not required. Without a connection packages installed from the ISO will not be updated and additional packages which may be necessary, such as video drivers, can not be downloaded. An Internet connection should be available after booting the ISO file from the GRUB menu.

To Install Ubuntu from an ISO Menuentry, use the procedures previously discussed to:

1.Download the appropriate ISO.

2.Move it to the desired location.

3.Create the GRUB 2 menuentry and update the GRUB configuration file.

4.Boot the ISO from the GRUB menu.

Note: If you have a large amount of RAM you may be able to use the toram option. This will allow the system to boot into memory and permit automatic unmounting of the isodevice during the installation. If you would like to try this option:

Press 'e' to edit the menuentry and add toram to the end of the menuentry's linux line:

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/<ISO-name.iso> noprompt noeject toram --
```

If /isodevice can be unmounted by the installer at the prompt, the installation will continue.

If you have insufficient memory and start the installation, the installer will be unable to unmount /isodevice, the install will fail and the system may freeze.

Since edits to the menuentry are not persistent, if the toram option fails, simply reboot and use the existing menuentry without editing it.

Once booted to the Ubuntu LiveCD desktop:

The /isodevice must be unmounted for a successful installation. If /isodevice cannot be unmounted by the installer, the installation will fail unless the user forces its unmounting.

If the toram option was not used or was unsuccessful, unmount /isodevice:

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo umount -l -r -f /isodevice
```

Start the installation procedure by double-clicking the "Install Ubuntu" icon.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Installing_Ubuntu_from_a_Menuentry_Boot)